# Bonobo Git Server - HTTP Error 500.19 - Code: 0x80070021

Tags: git, iis, bonobo

Is giving this error when accessing the system after installation:

OS: Windows 2012 R2

[image: Full error]

Comment: Did you read the "Config Error" and the "Config Source" parts of the message?

Comment: I read but do not know where to put

Comment: had the same problem solved using this one. http://andikanugraha.com/2015/09/install-bonobo-git-server-4-0-0-on-windows-10/

Comment: @nanangarsyad link is broken, use this instead https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-install-bonobo-git-server-on-windows

Answer (score 13):

I hit the same problem. I believed somehow IIS lost registration of MVC framework. Redo the registration by:

1. Windows 8+ / Windows Server 2012+ - Windows Features: IIS -> WWWS -> Application Development Features -> ASP.NET 4.5.
2. Other - Run

   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

with administrator privileges

Comment: This worked for me (2). I don't think I would have ever figured this out on my own. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed when doing this, the folder, "aspnet_client gets added to the website under the Sites directory of IIS Connections.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after running:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules
```

Comment: This does not work. I still get nearly the exact same error described in this question, but this answer does nothing to solve it.