# Bonobo Git Server Configruation: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error at line 71

Tags: iis, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, bonobo

I have tried to configure Bonobo Git Server. I have followed the included instructions, and after trying to visit the server for the first time, I get the following error:

[image]

[There is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633346/bonobo-git-server-http-error-500-19-code-0x80070021); however, it gives an error at one line prior and the solution the author answered (though not accepted) did not seem to affect the error occurring in my circumstances.

I am running Bonobo Git Server on Windows Server 2012R2 under IIS 8.5 using Azure. IIS is correctly configured in that I can view other sites.

Comment: create a new screenhot and crop it to the relevant parts, so we can actually read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message describes what the problem is, the `handlers` configuration section is locked at the server level. Select the server node and open the `Feature Delegation` section, set `Handler Mappings` to `Read/Write`

you can also run the following as an elevated administrator:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers
```

Comment: I did what Peter Hahndrof said. It worked but next I got error related to runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633346/bonobo-git-server-http-error-500-19-code-0x80070021 . The solution (By Lywx) is also in the same link.