# Bonobo Git Server Configuration : HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error at line 53

Tags: git, iis, iis-7.5, bonobo

I am trying to configure Bonobo Git server on a Windows 7 machine followed all the instructions but is encountering a HTTP Error 500.19 at line 53.

I know there is a  [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811308/bonobo-git-server-configruation-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-at-li) but I tried the accepted answer there and still encountering the same issue.

Below is the screenshots of my settings I even ran the command on the accepted answer

[image: DETAILED ERROR PAGE]

[image: THE ACCEPTED ANSWER SOLUTION HANDLER MAPPINGS READ/WRITE]

[image: THE ACCEPTED ANSWER COMMAND LINE SOLUTION]

[image: I FOLLOWED THE INSTRUCTIONS MADE SURE THE APPLIATION POOL RUNNING ON V4]

Comment: Post the detailed error page.

Comment: Hi Lex updated my question added the error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message indicates that the `<modules>` tag is locked, while the linked thread is for `<handlers>`. Thus, you should revise the command to unlock the proper tag by replacing the "handlers" part in the command with "modules",

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules
```

Pay attention to every details in the error page please, as it is really the most important part of such troubleshooting.

Comment: Oh thank you I thought I have read the error codes over and over again but still failed to see the difference.  Can you help me modify the script to unlock the tag <modules>?
Or is there a way thru the UI interface of IIS?

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks simply replace the "handlers" part in the command with "modules".

Comment: Accepted the answer the lock issue is resolved thank!.  Is it okay if you add the "replace the handlers part in the command with modules" solution to your answer to make it clear for other newbies.

Comment: @LexLi  I am a newbie. I am facing exactly same error.
I've tried myself, but failed to fix.
Can you help me to write code snip for "replace the handlers part in the command with modules"?

Comment: This is a great resource for similar, but different errors like that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7/